# How to define this recursive function

Tags: functions, notation, recursion

Is it possible to define a function such that

$$
fn(0)=a\\fn(1)=b(a-x^0)\\fn(2)=c(b(a-x^0)-x^1)\\fn(3)=d(c(b(a-x^0)-x^1)-x^2)\\ ...
$$

I was thinking it would involve something like $fn(n)=a_{n+1}(fn(n-1)-x^{n-1})$ but that breaks where $n=0$.

Comment: Then define a base case $fn(0) = a$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not?   You can say something like
$$ f(n) = \cases{a & if $n=0$\cr a_{n+1} (f(n-1)  - x^{n-1}) & if $n > 0$\cr}$$